# Bones need to be named exactly the same to copy pose data?

Tags: armature

I have two "wings" that are mirrored versions of each other, the difference being all the "left" and "right" bones have .R or .L respectively; however copy'ing and pasting pose data seems to only work if they have identical names.

Update: Sadly I still do not see a solution.

Comment: Do you mean copy the right wings pose, over to the left wing? In other words, mirror the pose?

Comment: Yes, but now I believe I figured out what's wrong.

1) I need to use "Paste mirrored/flipped pose", I tested this with a default Rigify rig and that worked.

2) The Z(zed)-axis rolls need to be aligned, so 50d and -50d or it'll be weird. Currently mine aren't aligned so I had initially dismissed this option when I tried it, but on experimenting with proper rig it works.

Once I have an oppurtunity this evening to apply it I'll leave an answer. :)